# Strange behavior of dispatch_get_main_queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, uiimage, grand-central-dispatch

I have a UIScrollView with enabled paging and I want to show some "pages" with images.

I load images of first page in a main thread and show it. Then I begin loading of other pages images in a background thread

```
    dispatch_async(loadingImagesQueue, ^{
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfImages; i++) {
                NSString *imagePath = [arrayWithImagePaths objectAtIndex:i];
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        NSLog(@"Posting notification\n\n");
                        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_NAME_IMAGE_PREPARED object:image];
                });
            }
    });
```

After posting notification some method call, witch creates a new page with loaded image.

I put log messages into my loading image and creating new page methods, and I expect that it will look like one message about loading image, then one message about creating new page.

But, for some reason, it loads all of the images first, and only after that start to create new pages. I can see it by my log messages. And the most strange thing that there is a big delay (about .5 second) between end of loading last image and begin creating a new page.

Can anyone explain, what's the reason of this strange behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling dispatch_async. If you want to perform the notification at that very moment in the main queue call `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ ...`. And just make sure to check you're not on the main thread already when dispatching anything on main queue (here, you are pretty much safe, but it's generally a good practice, otherwise you might encounter a lock).

So the full code would be

`if([NSThread isMainThread] == NO){
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {...`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I know the only difference between dispatch_async and dispatch_sync is that dispatch_sync makes bg thread wait the result of executing the block, while dispatch_async will allow bg thread to run at the same time. So both of them should run at that very moment.

Comment: The thing about dispatch_async is that it will not execute the block in the queue you specified but ENQUEUE it. That is why you are getting strange results. Blocks are enqueued in the main thread, and you're not actually sure when are they going to execute.